# Unexpected result of subtracting a NASM macro in an expression

Tags: assembly, nasm

I wrote the following code:

```
 section .text
    %define len msg-4
    global _start 
    msg: db "Thank you"
    var: dd 0x31323334

_start:
    mov ecx, msg
    debug:
    mov edx, var-len ; **** the problem is here
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h
    mov eax, 1 
    mov ebx, 1
    int 80h ; exit
```

I expected edx to hold the value 13, because `var-len= var-msg+4= 13` (the distance of the address of var from msg is 9, since msg is 9 bytes).       Therefore, I thought this code would print "Thank you".

But instead, edx got 5, and "Thank" was printed.

**Why does edx get 5 and not 13**?

Comment: Try using `section .data`.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: Why would he want to put read-only data there?  `.rodata` would be good, but it does just end up being in the `.text` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%define len msg-4` is a textual substitution, see below.

---

The normal way is to calculate the length with `$ - start` after an object.  Simply labelling the end works, too.

```
section .rodata           ; groups read-only together inside the .text section
    msg: db "Thank you"
    var: db 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x31   ; dd 0x31323334  ; Since you're passing these bytes to write(2), writing them separately is probably less confusing.  (x86 is little-endian, so they will come out "backwards")

    ;; apparently you want to include var as part of the message, for some reason
    msglen equ $ - msg    ; $ is the current position

    ;; msgend:            ; alternative: label the end.  There doesn't have to be a db or anything; it's fine to have multiple labels for the same address


section .text
    global _start 
_start:
    mov    edx, msglen        ; message length
    ;; mov edx, msgend - msg  ; alternative
```

---

#### Why you got `5`

**`%define` is a textual substitution, like the C preprocessor**.  It would have worked the way you expected if you'd used `(msg-4)`.  All the reasons for using `()` religiously in CPP macros apply here, too.

```
 %define len msg-4        ; first of all, this is a terrible name: it's not the length!
 mov    edx, var - len    ; expands to var-msg-4,  not var - (msg-4)

 %define msg_minus_varlen  (msg-4)
 mov    edx, var - msg_minus_varlen;  expands to var - (msg-4)
```

This is still a really confusing way to do it.  You're getting the length by subtracting two positions offset by the same amount from the buffer you're actually going to print.

Comment: Ohhh, "textual substitution", didn't know that (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the very top line - you say

```
 section .text
    %define len msg-4
    global _start 
    msg: db "Thank you"
    var: dd 0x31323334
```

msg - 4, not msg + 4. That right there explains the difference you are seeing.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* + instead of - would work, i.e. what's actually going on.

Comment: Snippets are pointless for anything but webby languages. They only support HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc. Just use regular old code-block formatting (indent each line by 4 spaces).